# How do I remove this horizontal scroll bar from my div/iframe?

Tags: html, scrollbar

I have searched and no one else seems to have my particular problem.  The scroll bar shows up, but without arrows on the side.

And I am shifting the page over so I can hide a side launch menu on the side of my Intranet site.

My code is:

```
<html>
<body>

<div style="overflow:hidden; width: 300; height:1000; position:absolute; left:-170px; top:-100px">
<iframe src="" style="overflow:hidden;" width=350 height=250 frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
</iframe></div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code i use on one of my sites... edit it as needed.

```
 <iframe src ="http://www.iframesite.com" width="768" height="2500" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"><p class="style1">Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
    </iframe>
```